# Laravel Clone rows

Tags: mysql, laravel, pdo

i m having an issue with the function i use. it works fine on localhost but on server it gives an error although it enters all the data. so it does clone the rows but give an error.
this is the function i use..

```
function postCopy( Request $request)
{
    foreach(\DB::select("SHOW COLUMNS FROM travellers ") as $column)
    {
        if( $column->Field != 'travellerID')
            $columns[] = $column->Field;
    }

    if(count($request->input('ids')) >=1)
    {
        $toCopy = implode(",",$request->input('ids'));
        $sql = "INSERT INTO travellers (".implode(",", $columns).") ";
        $sql .= " SELECT ".implode(",", $columns)." FROM travellers WHERE travellerID IN (".$toCopy.")";
        \DB::select($sql);
        return Redirect::to('travellers')->with('messagetext',\Lang::get('core.note_success'))->with('msgstatus','success');
    } else {

        return Redirect::to('travellers')->with('messagetext','Please select row to copy')->with('msgstatus','error');
    }   

}
```

on localhost , i have mysql 5.7.12 and php 5.6...  on server i have Mysql 5.6.35 and php 5.6

and this is the error message i get.

[image: Error Messages]

Comment: Why are you using DB::select(), if you are making an insert? Use DB::insert(). I recommend you to also give a look at Eloquent, since what you are attempting is not a best practise.

Comment: i will give it a go on my server and see.. thanks alot. can you give me a hint please about the best practise?

Comment: thanks alot.. fixed that issue..